# How to add a periodic task to a Service in minos?

Tags: python, microservices, minos, periodic

I want to add a method to my `minos.cqrs.Service` to be executed every day at 9:00 AM. How can I do that?

Here is my current code:

```py
from minos.cqrs import Service


class MyService(Service):

    async def task(self) -> None:
        print("Running periodic task...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a periodic task to a `minos.cqrs.Service` class, you can create a standard handling method and decorate it with the `@enroute.periodic.event` decorator from `minos.networks` and pass it a valid `cron` expression as argument ([`0 9 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_*_*_*) in your case).

Here is an example:

```py
from minos.cqrs import Service
from minos.networks import Request, enroute


class MyService(Service):

    @enroute.periodic.event("0 9 * * *")
    async def task(self, request: Request) -> None:
        print("Running periodic task...")
```